# Connection error C#

Tags: c#

```
private OleDbConnection conexao;
private Timer time = new Timer();

public void Conexao() //Conexão
{
   string strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|DB.accdb";
   conexao = new OleDbConnection(strcon);
}

void tabela()
{
   Conexao();
   conexao.Open();
   label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
   string bn = "select D2 from Planilha where D2='" + label1.Text + "'";
   textBox1.Text = label1.Text;
   OleDbCommand Queryyy = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao);
   OleDbDataReader drr;
   drr = Queryyy.ExecuteReader();
   if (drr.Read() == true)
   {
      try
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Hi");
      }
      catch (OleDbException ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
      }
   }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tabela();
}
```

Timer Interval = 1000

<sub>(click for larger view)</sub>
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g8QA.png]

I'm all afternoon trying to fix it but could not so I come here for help

Comment: Check for inner exceptions, and that the db file is not locked or corrupt, and is actually in the search path given.

Comment: On the exception dialog box, click on "View Detail..." to see more info about the exception, including the inner exception(s). They will hopefully give a more descriptive error message. I use this trick - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140076(v=office.10).aspx - to verify my connection strings as well.

Comment: also please post the exceptions in english - it helps :)

Comment: Click the "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" link and then paste the text here [as a edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19965644/edit). (be sure to higlight the text and press the `{ }` button to make it formatted properly.

Comment: Wait wait wait, does this happen EVERY timer tick, or only after 1 or more ticks? Your not closing/disposing the connection amigo, move the connection object out of that useless method and make it local to the function, then wrap it in a using clause. Next, instead of steady timer tickets, have it tick once, then reset the timer at the end of the work function. You don't want the reentrancy to start piling up new connections either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [asawyer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965644/connection-error-c-sharp#comment29719697_19965644) had it right I bet the problem is from the fact you are not handling your objects correctly, get rid of your class objects and work with `using` statements

```
public OleDbConnection Conexao() //Conexão
{
   string strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|DB.accdb";
   return new OleDbConnection(strcon);
}

void tabela()
{
    try
    {    
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        using(var conexao = Conexao())
        {   
           conexao.Open();
           label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
           string bn = "select D2 from Planilha where D2='" + label1.Text + "'";
           textBox1.Text = label1.Text;
           using(OleDbCommand Queryyy = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao))
           using(OleDbDataReader drr = Queryyy.ExecuteReader())
           {
               if (drr.Read() == true)
               {
                  try
                  {
                     MessageBox.Show("Hi");
                  }
                  catch (OleDbException ex)
                  {
                     MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
                  }
               }
           }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tabela();
}
```

---

Also from the fact that you are only reading the first column of the first row, you should use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`.

```
using(OleDbCommand Queryyy = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao))
{
   try
   {
       var result = Queryyy.ExecuteScalar();
       if (result != null)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Hi");
       }
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
    }
   }
}
```

---

You also should be using parametrized queries.

```
  label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  string bn = "select D2 from Planilha where D2=@param1";
  textBox1.Text = label1.Text;
  using(OleDbCommand Queryyy = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao))
  {
     Queryyy.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", label1.Text);
     //....
```

Comment: Now he'll just have to fix that sql injection problem :)

Comment: @asawyer I added a example of how to fix it. but there is no real risk as the only things that could be passed in would be the result from `DateTime.Now.ToString()`. However now that I look more, I find it extreemly unlikely he is going to find a record in `Planilha` that *exactly* matches the time he had when he ran `DateTime.Now.ToString()`

Comment: True, but that code is pretty smelly. Better to do it the right way every time, than to decide when its safe or not.